# Runtime error when trying to use css modules with react and snowpack

Tags: css, sass, module, proxy, snowpack

I have an issue when trying yo setup css modules with react and snowpack. Here is how to reproduce the issue:

`"snowpack": "^2.17.0",`

`"@snowpack/plugin-sass": "^1.1.1",`

Setup a new app using npx

`npx create-snowpack-app snowpack --template @snowpack/app-template-react-typescript`

`npm install @snowpack/plugin-sass --save-dev`

Add sass file
`app.sass`

```
.test
  width: 30px
  height: 30px
  background: red
```

App.tsx

`import styles from './app.sass'`

`<div className={styles.test}/>`

Snowpack `devOptions`

```
port: 8005,
open: 'none',
bundle: false,
out: 'dist'
```

Snowpack `plugins`

```
'@snowpack/plugin-react-refresh',
'@snowpack/plugin-dotenv',
'@snowpack/plugin-typescript',
'@snowpack/plugin-webpack',
'@snowpack/plugin-sass',
```

Run snowpack dev

`npm start => snowpack dev`

Error

`SyntaxError: The requested module './app.css.proxy.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to rename `app.sass` to `app.module.sass`

Snowpack supports CSS Modules using the `[name].module.css` naming convention. CSS Modules work just like normal CSS imports, but with a special default styles export that maps your original classnames to unique identifiers.

https://www.snowpack.dev/#import-css-modules